# How do I switch between local and remote dependencies with Node/NPM?

Tags: node.js

I have 2 files, `package-main.json` and `package-local.json`. The difference between these two is like this...

```
// local
"@jrg-material/button": "../components/packages/button",
//main
"@jrg-material/button": "latest",
```

I want a way to switch between these. Currently we copy the one we need to package.json, however, it is really easy to forget this step. Is there a way to do this without manual intervention (IE copying the file)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Leave version in `package.json` to latest so you don't have to do anything in production (just `npm install`) and create a script in `package.json` script section to

```
    "script": {
        "install-dev": "node change-to-dev-version-script.js; npm install"
    }
```

It's a json file, it's fairly straight forward to edit it.

For developer to develop locally, they will do `npm install-dev`.

For production, just use `npm install`

Comment: I don't understand what change-to-dev-version-script.js does?

Comment: Also how does this change it back after?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot, dev can still commit it my mistake. Sorry, my answer is wrong then.

Comment: Thank you anyway!

Comment: Write more about change-to-dev-version-script.js